# Permitting user agent (chrome) CORS requests programmatically

Tags: javascript, api, cors

I need to get some data from external API, from other domain.
I use test app, runned on localhost and I get error:

> Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I try to get access to: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ by **get** method

I did a lot of search and:

- I know that I can ask that API by using node.js, CURL, and also by running my frontend code in jest tests
- By using chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en also everything works correctly

But unfortunatelly by simply AJAX request on my page load I can't reach that API and get an error.

And my prediction is that user agent (chrome) somehow block my request.
I can't use chrome extension because I want also access my website from my mobile phone which can't get that desktop extension.

For now my solution is "proxy", node.js server which can access that API and flow looks like:

> FE
>
> -- ASK BE -->
>
> BE
>
> -- ASK API -->
>
> -- RESPONSE TO BE -->
>
> BE
>
> -- RESPONSE TO FE -->
>
> FE SHOWS EVERYTHING

FE - Frontend, BE - Backend (node.js proxy), API - external API

But I want to avoid unnecessary code on the BE. Maybe there is some solution?
Like some magical header which will tell chrome to let me pass to external domain without any additional extension?

Comment: No, you can't get around CORS on the front-end.

Comment: I don't think browsers allow you without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct you cannot bypass the CORS rules unless you are using jsonp and the server in question supports it.  When working with that ticker in the past I had to build a backend exactly as you describe with express.

`FE => BE => Ticker => BE => FE`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do that one clean way as described here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Set the header value

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

with your response to the first page load from server.

Comment: Api set that header because I can access it from node.js etc. but from FE site chrome block it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you pages uses HTML5,you can try using [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Another common solution is creating a proxy-server.

Comment: If I correctly understand idea it is only for posting messages not getting.